# How to enable all locales (character encodings) on Debian 11 (over SSH, in Bash)?

Tags: debian, files, locale, ntfs, character-encoding

I am unsure if I should not better ask:

***How to display Windows UTF-16 encoding in Linux?***

Since I just found out that Windows uses UTF-16LE to be exact:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/66072117/1997354

I am running Debian 11 (bullseye) on a headless server to which I connect with SSH. I am often copying files from SATA HDDs formatted to NTFS containing Win10. Some files, though, I see *crippled*, or how to say this, for example today I stumbled upon:

`KÃ_Â¼ndigung.pdf` which actually should be displayed as `Kündigung.pdf` ([deleted issue here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/740192/126755)).

another example `'LedovÃ© ostÅ'$'\302\231''Ã­ 1.avi'` which I am merely guessing is Czech `Ledové ostří.avi` or maybe `Ledově ostří.avi`.

```
ls 'LedovÃ© ostÅ'$'\302\231''Ã­ 1.avi' | hexdump -C
00000000  4c 65 64 6f 76 c3 83 c2  a9 20 6f 73 74 c3 85 c2  |Ledov.... ost...|
00000010  99 c3 83 c2 ad 20 31 2e  61 76 69 0a              |..... 1.avi.|
0000001c
```

---

Is it possible to somehow enable all locales simply to be able to correctly display and be able to copy all printable/possible characters?

I tried the following, but to no good end. All day in vain trying to achieve it.

Any help appreciated.

---

```
apt-cache policy locales-all
locales-all:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.31-13+deb11u5
  Version table:
     2.31-13+deb11u5 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages
```

afterward

```
apt-get install locales-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  locales-all
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 227 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 locales-all amd64 2.31-13+deb11u5 [10.8 MB]
Fetched 10.8 MB in 2s (5,539 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package locales-all.
(Reading database ... 209758 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../locales-all_2.31-13+deb11u5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking locales-all (2.31-13+deb11u5) ...
Setting up locales-all (2.31-13+deb11u5) ...
```

```
update-locale
```

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

selected ALL.

```
update-locale
```

```
locale-gen all

Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  aa_DJ.UTF-8... done
  aa_DJ.ISO-8859-1... done
  aa_ER.UTF-8... done
  aa_ER.UTF-8@saaho... done
  aa_ET.UTF-8... done
  af_ZA.UTF-8... done
  af_ZA.ISO-8859-1... done
  agr_PE.UTF-8... done
  ak_GH.UTF-8... done
  am_ET.UTF-8... done
  an_ES.UTF-8... done
  an_ES.ISO-8859-15... done
  anp_IN.UTF-8... done
  ar_AE.UTF-8... done
  ar_AE.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_BH.UTF-8... done
  ar_BH.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_DZ.UTF-8... done
  ar_DZ.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_EG.UTF-8... done
  ar_EG.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_IN.UTF-8... done
  ar_IQ.UTF-8... done
  ar_IQ.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_JO.UTF-8... done
  ar_JO.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_KW.UTF-8... done
  ar_KW.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_LB.UTF-8... done
  ar_LB.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_LY.UTF-8... done
  ar_LY.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_MA.UTF-8... done
  ar_MA.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_OM.UTF-8... done
  ar_OM.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_QA.UTF-8... done
  ar_QA.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_SA.UTF-8... done
  ar_SA.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_SD.UTF-8... done
  ar_SD.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_SS.UTF-8... done
  ar_SY.UTF-8... done
  ar_SY.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_TN.UTF-8... done
  ar_TN.ISO-8859-6... done
  ar_YE.UTF-8... done
  ar_YE.ISO-8859-6... done
  ayc_PE.UTF-8... done
  az_AZ.UTF-8... done
  az_IR.UTF-8... done
  as_IN.UTF-8... done
  ast_ES.UTF-8... done
  ast_ES.ISO-8859-15... done
  be_BY.UTF-8... done
  be_BY.CP1251... done
  be_BY.UTF-8@latin... done
  bem_ZM.UTF-8... done
  ber_DZ.UTF-8... done
  ber_MA.UTF-8... done
  bg_BG.UTF-8... done
  bg_BG.CP1251... done
  bhb_IN.UTF-8... done
  bho_IN.UTF-8... done
  bho_NP.UTF-8... done
  bi_VU.UTF-8... done
  bn_BD.UTF-8... done
  bn_IN.UTF-8... done
  bo_CN.UTF-8... done
  bo_IN.UTF-8... done
  br_FR.UTF-8... done
  br_FR.ISO-8859-1... done
  br_FR.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  brx_IN.UTF-8... done
  bs_BA.UTF-8... done
  bs_BA.ISO-8859-2... done
  byn_ER.UTF-8... done
  ca_AD.UTF-8... done
  ca_AD.ISO-8859-15... done
  ca_ES.UTF-8... done
  ca_ES.ISO-8859-1... done
  ca_ES.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  ca_ES.UTF-8@valencia... done
  ca_FR.UTF-8... done
  ca_FR.ISO-8859-15... done
  ca_IT.UTF-8... done
  ca_IT.ISO-8859-15... done
  ce_RU.UTF-8... done
  chr_US.UTF-8... done
  cmn_TW.UTF-8... done
  crh_UA.UTF-8... done
  cs_CZ.UTF-8... done
  cs_CZ.ISO-8859-2... done
  csb_PL.UTF-8... done
  cv_RU.UTF-8... done
  cy_GB.UTF-8... done
  cy_GB.ISO-8859-14... done
  da_DK.UTF-8... done
  da_DK.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_AT.UTF-8... done
  de_AT.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_AT.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  de_BE.UTF-8... done
  de_BE.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_BE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  de_CH.UTF-8... done
  de_CH.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_DE.UTF-8... done
  de_DE.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_DE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  de_IT.UTF-8... done
  de_IT.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_LI.UTF-8... done
  de_LU.UTF-8... done
  de_LU.ISO-8859-1... done
  de_LU.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  doi_IN.UTF-8... done
  dsb_DE.UTF-8... done
  dv_MV.UTF-8... done
  dz_BT.UTF-8... done
  el_GR.UTF-8... done
  el_GR.ISO-8859-7... done
  el_GR.ISO-8859-7@euro... done
  el_CY.UTF-8... done
  el_CY.ISO-8859-7... done
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.ISO-8859-15... done
  en_DK.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_GB.ISO-8859-15... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_IE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  en_IL.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_SC.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_US.ISO-8859-15... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.ISO-8859-1... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.ISO-8859-1... done
  eo.UTF-8... done
  es_AR.UTF-8... done
  es_AR.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_BO.UTF-8... done
  es_BO.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_CL.UTF-8... done
  es_CL.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_CO.UTF-8... done
  es_CO.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_CR.UTF-8... done
  es_CR.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_CU.UTF-8... done
  es_DO.UTF-8... done
  es_DO.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_EC.UTF-8... done
  es_EC.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_ES.UTF-8... done
  es_ES.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_ES.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  es_GT.UTF-8... done
  es_GT.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_HN.UTF-8... done
  es_HN.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_MX.UTF-8... done
  es_MX.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_NI.UTF-8... done
  es_NI.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_PA.UTF-8... done
  es_PA.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_PE.UTF-8... done
  es_PE.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_PR.UTF-8... done
  es_PR.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_PY.UTF-8... done
  es_PY.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_SV.UTF-8... done
  es_SV.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_US.UTF-8... done
  es_US.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_UY.UTF-8... done
  es_UY.ISO-8859-1... done
  es_VE.UTF-8... done
  es_VE.ISO-8859-1... done
  et_EE.UTF-8... done
  et_EE.ISO-8859-1... done
  et_EE.ISO-8859-15... done
  eu_ES.UTF-8... done
  eu_ES.ISO-8859-1... done
  eu_ES.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  eu_FR.UTF-8... done
  eu_FR.ISO-8859-1... done
  eu_FR.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  fa_IR.UTF-8... done
  ff_SN.UTF-8... done
  fi_FI.UTF-8... done
  fi_FI.ISO-8859-1... done
  fi_FI.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  fil_PH.UTF-8... done
  fo_FO.UTF-8... done
  fo_FO.ISO-8859-1... done
  fr_BE.UTF-8... done
  fr_BE.ISO-8859-1... done
  fr_BE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  fr_CA.UTF-8... done
  fr_CA.ISO-8859-1... done
  fr_CH.UTF-8... done
  fr_CH.ISO-8859-1... done
  fr_FR.UTF-8... done
  fr_FR.ISO-8859-1... done
  fr_FR.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  fr_LU.UTF-8... done
  fr_LU.ISO-8859-1... done
  fr_LU.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  fur_IT.UTF-8... done
  fy_NL.UTF-8... done
  fy_DE.UTF-8... done
  ga_IE.UTF-8... done
  ga_IE.ISO-8859-1... done
  ga_IE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  gd_GB.UTF-8... done
  gd_GB.ISO-8859-15... done
  gez_ER.UTF-8... done
  gez_ER.UTF-8@abegede... done
  gez_ET.UTF-8... done
  gez_ET.UTF-8@abegede... done
  gl_ES.UTF-8... done
  gl_ES.ISO-8859-1... done
  gl_ES.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  gu_IN.UTF-8... done
  gv_GB.UTF-8... done
  gv_GB.ISO-8859-1... done
  ha_NG.UTF-8... done
  hak_TW.UTF-8... done
  he_IL.UTF-8... done
  he_IL.ISO-8859-8... done
  hi_IN.UTF-8... done
  hif_FJ.UTF-8... done
  hne_IN.UTF-8... done
  hr_HR.UTF-8... done
  hr_HR.ISO-8859-2... done
  hsb_DE.UTF-8... done
  hsb_DE.ISO-8859-2... done
  ht_HT.UTF-8... done
  hu_HU.UTF-8... done
  hu_HU.ISO-8859-2... done
  hy_AM.UTF-8... done
  hy_AM.ARMSCII-8... done
  ia_FR.UTF-8... done
  id_ID.UTF-8... done
  id_ID.ISO-8859-1... done
  ig_NG.UTF-8... done
  ik_CA.UTF-8... done
  is_IS.UTF-8... done
  is_IS.ISO-8859-1... done
  it_CH.UTF-8... done
  it_CH.ISO-8859-1... done
  it_IT.UTF-8... done
  it_IT.ISO-8859-1... done
  it_IT.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  iu_CA.UTF-8... done
  ja_JP.UTF-8... done
  ja_JP.EUC-JP... done
  ka_GE.UTF-8... done
  ka_GE.GEORGIAN-PS... done
  kab_DZ.UTF-8... done
  kk_KZ.UTF-8... done
  kk_KZ.PT154... done
  kk_KZ.RK1048... done
  kl_GL.UTF-8... done
  kl_GL.ISO-8859-1... done
  km_KH.UTF-8... done
  kn_IN.UTF-8... done
  ko_KR.UTF-8... done
  ko_KR.EUC-KR... done
  kok_IN.UTF-8... done
  ks_IN.UTF-8... done
  ks_IN.UTF-8@devanagari... done
  ku_TR.UTF-8... done
  ku_TR.ISO-8859-9... done
  kw_GB.UTF-8... done
  kw_GB.ISO-8859-1... done
  ky_KG.UTF-8... done
  lb_LU.UTF-8... done
  lg_UG.UTF-8... done
  lg_UG.ISO-8859-10... done
  li_BE.UTF-8... done
  li_NL.UTF-8... done
  lij_IT.UTF-8... done
  ln_CD.UTF-8... done
  lo_LA.UTF-8... done
  lt_LT.UTF-8... done
  lt_LT.ISO-8859-13... done
  lv_LV.UTF-8... done
  lv_LV.ISO-8859-13... done
  lzh_TW.UTF-8... done
  mag_IN.UTF-8... done
  mai_IN.UTF-8... done
  mai_NP.UTF-8... done
  mfe_MU.UTF-8... done
  mg_MG.UTF-8... done
  mg_MG.ISO-8859-15... done
  mhr_RU.UTF-8... done
  mi_NZ.UTF-8... done
  mi_NZ.ISO-8859-13... done
  miq_NI.UTF-8... done
  mjw_IN.UTF-8... done
  mk_MK.UTF-8... done
  mk_MK.ISO-8859-5... done
  ml_IN.UTF-8... done
  mn_MN.UTF-8... done
  mni_IN.UTF-8... done
  mnw_MM.UTF-8... done
  mr_IN.UTF-8... done
  ms_MY.UTF-8... done
  ms_MY.ISO-8859-1... done
  mt_MT.UTF-8... done
  mt_MT.ISO-8859-3... done
  my_MM.UTF-8... done
  nan_TW.UTF-8... done
  nan_TW.UTF-8@latin... done
  nb_NO.UTF-8... done
  nb_NO.ISO-8859-1... done
  nds_DE.UTF-8... done
  nds_NL.UTF-8... done
  ne_NP.UTF-8... done
  nhn_MX.UTF-8... done
  niu_NU.UTF-8... done
  niu_NZ.UTF-8... done
  nl_AW.UTF-8... done
  nl_BE.UTF-8... done
  nl_BE.ISO-8859-1... done
  nl_BE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  nl_NL.UTF-8... done
  nl_NL.ISO-8859-1... done
  nl_NL.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  nn_NO.UTF-8... done
  nn_NO.ISO-8859-1... done
  nr_ZA.UTF-8... done
  nso_ZA.UTF-8... done
  oc_FR.UTF-8... done
  oc_FR.ISO-8859-1... done
  om_ET.UTF-8... done
  om_KE.UTF-8... done
  om_KE.ISO-8859-1... done
  or_IN.UTF-8... done
  os_RU.UTF-8... done
  pa_IN.UTF-8... done
  pa_PK.UTF-8... done
  pap_AW.UTF-8... done
  pap_CW.UTF-8... done
  pl_PL.UTF-8... done
  pl_PL.ISO-8859-2... done
  ps_AF.UTF-8... done
  pt_BR.UTF-8... done
  pt_BR.ISO-8859-1... done
  pt_PT.UTF-8... done
  pt_PT.ISO-8859-1... done
  pt_PT.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  quz_PE.UTF-8... done
  raj_IN.UTF-8... done
  ro_RO.UTF-8... done
  ro_RO.ISO-8859-2... done
  ru_RU.UTF-8... done
  ru_RU.KOI8-R... done
  ru_RU.ISO-8859-5... done
  ru_RU.CP1251... done
  ru_UA.UTF-8... done
  ru_UA.KOI8-U... done
  rw_RW.UTF-8... done
  sa_IN.UTF-8... done
  sah_RU.UTF-8... done
  sat_IN.UTF-8... done
  sc_IT.UTF-8... done
  sd_IN.UTF-8... done
  sd_IN.UTF-8@devanagari... done
  se_NO.UTF-8... done
  sgs_LT.UTF-8... done
  shn_MM.UTF-8... done
  shs_CA.UTF-8... done
  si_LK.UTF-8... done
  sid_ET.UTF-8... done
  sk_SK.UTF-8... done
  sk_SK.ISO-8859-2... done
  sl_SI.UTF-8... done
  sl_SI.ISO-8859-2... done
  sm_WS.UTF-8... done
  so_DJ.UTF-8... done
  so_DJ.ISO-8859-1... done
  so_ET.UTF-8... done
  so_KE.UTF-8... done
  so_KE.ISO-8859-1... done
  so_SO.UTF-8... done
  so_SO.ISO-8859-1... done
  sq_AL.UTF-8... done
  sq_AL.ISO-8859-1... done
  sq_MK.UTF-8... done
  sr_ME.UTF-8... done
  sr_RS.UTF-8... done
  sr_RS.UTF-8@latin... done
  ss_ZA.UTF-8... done
  st_ZA.UTF-8... done
  st_ZA.ISO-8859-1... done
  sv_FI.UTF-8... done
  sv_FI.ISO-8859-1... done
  sv_FI.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  sv_SE.UTF-8... done
  sv_SE.ISO-8859-1... done
  sv_SE.ISO-8859-15... done
  sw_KE.UTF-8... done
  sw_TZ.UTF-8... done
  szl_PL.UTF-8... done
  ta_IN.UTF-8... done
  ta_LK.UTF-8... done
  tcy_IN.UTF-8... done
  te_IN.UTF-8... done
  tg_TJ.UTF-8... done
  tg_TJ.KOI8-T... done
  th_TH.UTF-8... done
  th_TH.TIS-620... done
  the_NP.UTF-8... done
  ti_ER.UTF-8... done
  ti_ET.UTF-8... done
  tig_ER.UTF-8... done
  tk_TM.UTF-8... done
  tl_PH.UTF-8... done
  tl_PH.ISO-8859-1... done
  tn_ZA.UTF-8... done
  to_TO.UTF-8... done
  tpi_PG.UTF-8... done
  tr_CY.UTF-8... done
  tr_CY.ISO-8859-9... done
  tr_TR.UTF-8... done
  tr_TR.ISO-8859-9... done
  ts_ZA.UTF-8... done
  tt_RU.UTF-8... done
  tt_RU.UTF-8@iqtelif... done
  ug_CN.UTF-8... done
  uk_UA.UTF-8... done
  uk_UA.KOI8-U... done
  unm_US.UTF-8... done
  ur_IN.UTF-8... done
  ur_PK.UTF-8... done
  uz_UZ.UTF-8... done
  uz_UZ.ISO-8859-1... done
  uz_UZ.UTF-8@cyrillic... done
  ve_ZA.UTF-8... done
  vi_VN.UTF-8... done
  wa_BE.UTF-8... done
  wa_BE.ISO-8859-1... done
  wa_BE.ISO-8859-15@euro... done
  wae_CH.UTF-8... done
  wal_ET.UTF-8... done
  wo_SN.UTF-8... done
  xh_ZA.UTF-8... done
  xh_ZA.ISO-8859-1... done
  yi_US.UTF-8... done
  yi_US.CP1255... done
  yo_NG.UTF-8... done
  yue_HK.UTF-8... done
  yuw_PG.UTF-8... done
  zh_CN.UTF-8... done
  zh_CN.GB18030... done
  zh_CN.GBK... done
  zh_CN.GB2312... done
  zh_HK.UTF-8... done
  zh_HK.BIG5-HKSCS... done
  zh_SG.UTF-8... done
  zh_SG.GBK... done
  zh_SG.GB2312... done
  zh_TW.UTF-8... done
  zh_TW.EUC-TW... done
  zh_TW.BIG5... done
  zu_ZA.UTF-8... done
  zu_ZA.ISO-8859-1... done
Generation complete.
```

I even rebooted the server,

### but issue persists - no improvement

I still do not see German characters in this file names for instance:

```
ll Downloads/Fila\ Martin\ *

-rwxrwxrwx 2 root root 180K 2021-Dec-23 'Downloads/Fila Martin - KÃ_Â¼ndigung.pdf'
```

---

Elaboration:

```
\ls -l Fila\ Martin\ -\ KÃ_Â¼ndigung.pdf | hexdump -C
00000000  2d 72 77 78 72 77 78 72  77 78 20 32 20 72 6f 6f  |-rwxrwxrwx 2 roo|
00000010  74 20 72 6f 6f 74 20 31  38 33 35 31 36 20 44 65  |t root 183516 De|
00000020  63 20 32 33 20 20 32 30  32 31 20 46 69 6c 61 20  |c 23  2021 Fila |
00000030  4d 61 72 74 69 6e 20 2d  20 4b c3 83 5f c3 82 c2  |Martin - K.._...|
00000040  bc 6e 64 69 67 75 6e 67  2e 70 64 66 0a           |.ndigung.pdf.|
0000004d
```

and

```
locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

---

I found this possibly good resource, but as I do not understand Unicode, it is over my league:
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch08.en.html

[A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) tried to help me, but for some reason, it did not work out:

> It's filename, not their content anyway. I deleted my previous comment because even Kündigung wouldn't match the 2nd part with a wrong double encoding (`echo -n ü | iconv -f iso-8859-1 | xxd -p` gives `c383c2bc` not `c382c2bc` which in the other way around gives a `¼` . Also German was supposed to have switched to `iso-8859-15` where `¼` didn't exist anymore anyway. I guess the way the file was passed around might have altered its name in strange ways.

Last info that just came to my mind is how I mounted the NTFS SATA disk partition:

```
mount /dev/sdX4 /mnt/something/
```

As you can see, I did not specify any extra switch or passed any argument than necessary.

---

I am connecting from Linux Mint 21.1 Vera to that Debian server.

Comment: It would be good to know if the filenames are ok *before* you copy them. If they were wrong to begin with, then no mount option might be able to fix it. For example you guess the second filename is Czech, is there a way to get the actual original filename as seen when mounted from Linux? And double check it is also ok in Windows? By the way, if it's Unicode, with the right encoding, you should be able to see all names within a single locale, any one that handles Unicode.

Answer (score -2):

> Is it possible to somehow enable all locales

Short answer is: No

The problem here is that if you have a single byte with value in the range 128-255 the computer cannot guess: a letter from which locale that byte represents. That is why you have to tell the OS which code page (locale) to use - letters from which alphabet to draw on screen if the file name has byte with value above ASCII.

That is why the UTF8 is gaining popularity. In UTF8 the string can have an unprintable byte which says: this and next few bytes describes a letter which should be printed from a different code page. That allows us to have a multi-language string without manually switching locales.

---

You currently have files created in several different locales. And you want to bring them into one common. The easiest solution to this would be to use `rename` tool.

Switch to national locale, so the file name is readable, do `rename -u Kündigung.pdf`. The `-u` key will rename file from current locale into unicode.

Comment: Look at the hex dump: the faulty characters are encoded using multiple bytes. And that is *not* how UTF-8 works.

Comment: That is still not how UTF-8 works.